# Why does GitBash show name of branch (master) in terminal when there is no branch pointer?

Tags: git, git-bash

```
User@DESKTOP ~/gitr/locals/stackrep
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/User/gitr/locals/stackrep/.git/
```

I was confused when started to learn git. What does mean a "master" here? Is just a feature of GitBash? Is it a simple clue like "current name for branch for next commit is 'master' "?

```
User@DESKTOP ~/gitr/locals/stackrep (master)
$ touch text.txt

User@DESKTOP ~/gitr/locals/stackrep (master)
$ git add .

User@DESKTOP ~/gitr/locals/stackrep (master)
$ git commit -m "txt"
[master (root-commit) b8023b1] txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 text.txt
```

Only after first commit "master" (or any name by git branch -M   ) is created in `C:\Users\User\gitr\locals\stackrep\.git\refs\heads\`

Comment: `master` is the original name of the _default_ branch so for a new repo, when you start using it, you will be working on `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/4991b615ecfc2a56e8086e49fc623229eb2a5926/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L482 the prompt reads the head from `.git/HEAD` file, which contains `ref: refs/heads/master`.

Comment: So, I was right in my assumption.